# extract file from zip that is inside another zip

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I have a file structure as so:

```
archive.zip contains:
    directory archive which contains:
        zip_1.zip contains:
            file.txt
        zip_2.zip
        zip_3.zip
```

Is there a way that I can extract file.txt without having to unzip archive.zip?  I'm currently extracting zip_1.zip with

```
unzip -j archive.zip "archive/zip_1.zip" -d "/path/where/zip_1/will/go"
```

then extracting file.txt out of the resulting zip_1.zip .

Is there a clean way to extract file.txt in this situation?

Comment: due to the nature of zip, seeking the file appears to be mandatory. This precludes one-pass stream handling like with eg .tar.gz (using tar --to-stdout -xzf file.tar.gz innerfile.tar.gz | tar -xzf - ), even if unzip provides options -c and -p to extract to stdout. So beside a specialized program made at least in perl or python to store intermediate data in memory, this doesn't appear to be scriptable without using temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

Here can be [your solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1079182/extract-file-from-a-zip-inside-another-zip-using-7z-command-line) using [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)

Comment: Should have mentioned that I'm unable to use 7zip on the remote server, or else I would have followed that solution.